# Ruby on Rails model not recognized for preload?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, mariadb

I am trying to join two tables in a mariadb database. The halls table and the residence_staff tables. The goal is to display all the names of the managers for each hall and what hall they work in. When I run the application I get this error: Hall(hallId: integer, hallName: text, street: text, city: text, postcode: integer, phoneNumber: integer, sfaffNumber: integer) was not recognized for preload

I have no idea what this means.

**Halls model**

```
class Hall < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ResidenceStaffs
end
```

**residence_staff Model**

```
class ResidenceStaff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Hall

      class << self

        def managers
          where(position: 'manager')
        end
      end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @residence_staff = ResidenceStaff.all
    @residence_staff_managers = ResidenceStaff.managers.includes(Hall)
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<div>
  <% @residence_staff_managers.each do |residence_staff| %>
    <%= residence_staff.fName%>
    <%= residence_staff.hallName%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have a feeling it is an issue with database mygrations but I am not entirely sure. Also,

**Schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180426051412) do

  create_table "advisor", primary_key: "advisorNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.text "position", null: false
    t.text "deptName", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.string "email", limit: 100, null: false
    t.integer "roomNumber", null: false
    t.index ["advisorNumber"], name: "Advisor_advisorNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "Advisor_email_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "hall_of_residences", primary_key: "hallName", id: :string, limit: 50, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.text "hall", null: false
    t.integer "staffNumber", null: false
    t.index ["hallName"], name: "HallOfResidence_hallName_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["staffNumber"], name: "HallOfResidence_ResidenceStaff_staffNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "halls", primary_key: "hallId", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "hallName", limit: 255, null: false
    t.text "street", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.integer "sfaffNumber", null: false
    t.index ["sfaffNumber"], name: "halls_residence_staffs_staffNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "invoice", primary_key: "invoiceNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "semester", limit: 50
    t.date "paymentDue"
    t.text "studentFName", null: false
    t.text "studentLName", null: false
    t.string "roomLocation", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "leaseNumber", null: false
    t.index ["invoiceNumber"], name: "Invoice_invoiceNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["leaseNumber"], name: "Invoice_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "invoice_payment", primary_key: "paymentID", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.date "datePayed", null: false
    t.string "method", limit: 50, null: false
    t.date "dateOfFirstReminder"
    t.date "dateOfSecondReminder"
    t.integer "muNum", null: false
    t.index ["muNum"], name: "InvoicePayment_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["paymentID"], name: "InvoicePayment_paymentID_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "lease", id: false, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "leaseNumber", null: false
    t.string "duration", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "studentFName", null: false
    t.text "studentLName", null: false
    t.integer "placeNumber", null: false
    t.integer "roomNumber", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.date "dateToLeave", null: false
    t.date "dateToEnter", null: false
    t.integer "mUNum", null: false
    t.index ["leaseNumber"], name: "Lease_leaseNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["mUNum"], name: "Lease_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["placeNumber"], name: "Lease_placeNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "next_of_kin", primary_key: "nextID", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.text "relationship", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 100, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.integer "mUNum", null: false
    t.index ["mUNum"], name: "NextOfKin_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["nextID"], name: "NextOfKin_nextID_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "parking_lot", primary_key: "lotNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "lotName", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 100, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "maxSpace", null: false
    t.integer "availability", null: false
    t.index ["lotNumber"], name: "ParkingLot_lotNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "residence_staffs", primary_key: "staffNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.string "email", limit: 100, null: false
    t.text "homeCity", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postal", null: false
    t.date "dob", null: false
    t.text "gender"
    t.text "position", null: false
    t.string "location", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.integer "inspectedRoomID", null: false
    t.string "hall", limit: 50, null: false
    t.index ["inspectedRoomID"], name: "ResidenceStaff_StudentApartmentInspection_inspectedRoomID_fk"
    t.index ["staffNumber"], name: "ResidenceStaff_staffNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "room", primary_key: "placeNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "rentRate", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "availability", null: false
    t.integer "roomNumber"
    t.string "hallName", limit: 50
    t.integer "apartmentNumber"
    t.index ["apartmentNumber"], name: "room_StudentFlats_apartmentNumber_fk"
    t.index ["hallName"], name: "room_HallOfResidence_hallName_fk"
  end

  create_table "staff", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "fName"
  end

  create_table "student", primary_key: "mUNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 100, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.string "email", limit: 100, null: false
    t.date "dob", null: false
    t.text "gender"
    t.text "standing", null: false
    t.text "nationality", null: false
    t.string "specialNeeds", limit: 100
    t.text "major", null: false
    t.string "statusOfStudent", limit: 100
    t.text "minor"
    t.text "comments"
    t.integer "advisorNumber", null: false
    t.index ["advisorNumber"], name: "Student_Advisor_advisorNumber_fk"
    t.index ["email"], name: "Student_email_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["mUNumber"], name: "Student_mUNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "student_apartment_inspection", primary_key: "inspectedRoomID", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "inspectorName", null: false
    t.date "dateOfInspection", null: false
    t.text "apartmentCondition", null: false
    t.text "comments"
    t.index ["inspectedRoomID"], name: "StudentApartmentInspection_inspectedRoomID_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "student_flats", primary_key: "apartmentNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "numberOfRooms", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "leaseID", null: false
    t.index ["apartmentNumber"], name: "StudentFlats_apartmentNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["leaseID"], name: "StudentFlats_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "vehicle", primary_key: "vNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "plateNumber", limit: 10, null: false
    t.text "color", null: false
    t.text "manufacturer", null: false
    t.string "brand", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "mUNum", null: false
    t.integer "lotNumber", null: false
    t.index ["lotNumber"], name: "Vehicle_ParkingLot_lotNumber_fk"
    t.index ["mUNum"], name: "Vehicle_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["plateNumber"], name: "Vehicle_plateNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["vNumber"], name: "Vehicle_vNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "hall_of_residences", "residence_staffs", column: "staffNumber", primary_key: "staffNumber", name: "HallOfResidence_ResidenceStaff_staffNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "halls", "residence_staffs", column: "sfaffNumber", primary_key: "staffNumber", name: "halls_residence_staffs_staffNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "invoice", "lease", column: "leaseNumber", primary_key: "leaseNumber", name: "Invoice_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "invoice_payment", "student", column: "muNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "InvoicePayment_Student_mUNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "lease", "student", column: "mUNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "Lease_Student_mUNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "next_of_kin", "student", column: "mUNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "NextOfKin_Student_mUNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "residence_staffs", "student_apartment_inspection", column: "inspectedRoomID", primary_key: "inspectedRoomID", name: "ResidenceStaff_StudentApartmentInspection_inspectedRoomID_fk"
  add_foreign_key "room", "hall_of_residences", column: "hallName", primary_key: "hallName", name: "room_HallOfResidence_hallName_fk"
  add_foreign_key "room", "student_flats", column: "apartmentNumber", primary_key: "apartmentNumber", name: "room_StudentFlats_apartmentNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "student", "advisor", column: "advisorNumber", primary_key: "advisorNumber", name: "Student_Advisor_advisorNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "student_flats", "lease", column: "leaseID", primary_key: "leaseNumber", name: "StudentFlats_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "vehicle", "parking_lot", column: "lotNumber", primary_key: "lotNumber", name: "Vehicle_ParkingLot_lotNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "vehicle", "student", column: "mUNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "Vehicle_Student_mUNumber_fk"
end
```

Comment: It should be `ResidenceStaff.managers.includes(:hall)`

Comment: `belongs_to` and `has_many` use snake_case. Like, `belongs_to :hall`. Not, `belongs_to :Hall`. And, what @MarekLipka said.

Comment: That did work but now it says unidentified method 'hallName' but you can see that it is there in the schema.rb?

Comment: It should also be `has_many :residence_staffs`.

Comment: Yeah, it is in schema, but in `halls` table. You try to call this method on `ResidenceStaff` instance. If I were you, I would take some time to learn basics and conventions in programming Ruby on Rails applications - e.g. using camelCase in column names isn't considered a good practice in RoR apps.

Comment: Ok it is correctily displaying the names now so hell ya! But it is not displaying the name of the hall?

Comment: I want to get the hallName field out of the halls table by joining it to the residence_staff table

Comment: @MarekLipka I realize that it is in the halls table i did that on purpose. I want to join the halls and residence_staff tables to get the info out of the halls table. Can you at least confirm that this is possible? I've been trying this for 3 days and im beginning to think you can't do that in rails

Answer (score 1):

You need to change these parts of code

```
has_many :ResidenceStaffs
```

to

```
has_many :residence_staffs, primary_key: 'hallId', foreign_key: 'hall_id'
```

Then change

```
belongs_to :Hall
```

on

```
belongs_to :hall, :primary_key: 'hallId', foreign_key: 'hall_id'
```

Change by migrations in the schema for residence_staffs

```
t.string "hall", limit: 50, null: false
```

On

```
t.integer "hall_id", null: false
```

You can review [this doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to get familiar with active record associations

Comment: This did not change anything. Any other advice?

Comment: And error stays the same?
Please provide full error text.
And make sure that database schema changed. If you edit the schema manually without migration database is not changed.
I've added some changes.